# py4JJavaError. pyspark applying function to column

Tags: python, pyspark

spark = 2.x

New to pyspark.

While encoding date related columns for training DNN keep on facing error mentioned in the title.

from df

```
day    month    ...
 1       1
 2       3 
 3       1      ...
```

I am trying to get cos, sine value for each column in order to capture their cyclic nature.

When applying function to column in pyspark udf worked fine until now. But below code doesn't work

```
def to_cos(x, _max):
    return np.sin(2*np.pi*x / _max)

to_cos_udf = udf(to_cos, DecimalType())

df = df.withColumn("month", to_cos_udf("month", 12))
```

I've tried it with IntegerType and tried it with only one variable `def to_cos(x)` however none of them seem to work and outputs:

`Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling 0.24702.showString.`

Answer (score 0):

Since you havent shared the entire Stacktrack from the error , not sure what is the actual error which is causing the failure

However by the code snippets you have shared , Firstly you need to update your UDF definition as below -

Will passing arguments to a UDF function using it with `lambda` is probably the best approach towards it , apart from that you can use [partial](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html)

### Data Preparation

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'month':[i for i in range(0,12)],    
})

sparkDF = sql.createDataFrame(df)

sparkDF.show()

+-----+
|month|
+-----+
|    0|
|    1|
|    2|
|    3|
|    4|
|    5|
|    6|
|    7|
|    8|
|    9|
|   10|
|   11|
+-----+
```

### Custom UDF

```
def to_cos(x,_max):

    try:
        res = np.sin(2*np.pi*x / _max)
    except Exception as e:
        res = 0.0
        
    return float(res)

max_cos = 12

to_cos_udf = F.udf(lambda x: to_cos(x,max_cos),FloatType())

sparkDF = sparkDF.withColumn('month_cos',to_cos_udf('month'))

sparkDF.show()

+-----+-------------+
|month|    month_cos|
+-----+-------------+
|    0|          0.0|
|    1|          0.5|
|    2|    0.8660254|
|    3|          1.0|
|    4|    0.8660254|
|    5|          0.5|
|    6|1.2246469E-16|
|    7|         -0.5|
|    8|   -0.8660254|
|    9|         -1.0|
|   10|   -0.8660254|
|   11|         -0.5|
+-----+-------------+
```

### Custom UDF - Partial

```
from functools import partial

partial_func = partial(to_cos,_max=max_cos)

to_cos_partial_udf = F.udf(partial_func)

sparkDF = sparkDF.withColumn('month_cos',to_cos_partial_udf('month'))

sparkDF.show()

+-----+--------------------+
|month|           month_cos|
+-----+--------------------+
|    0|                 0.0|
|    1| 0.49999999999999994|
|    2|  0.8660254037844386|
|    3|                 1.0|
|    4|  0.8660254037844388|
|    5| 0.49999999999999994|
|    6|1.224646799147353...|
|    7| -0.4999999999999998|
|    8| -0.8660254037844384|
|    9|                -1.0|
|   10| -0.8660254037844386|
|   11| -0.5000000000000004|
+-----+--------------------+
```